# It's possible to use scrollabeView like this in Appcelerator?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to have a scrollabeView (pagingControl) exactly like this [image](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1200964/screenshots/3812962/todo_concept_iphonex_30fps.gif), where I can show 2 pages at the same time or more and swipe between them on Ios And Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by creating this widget [com.developatic.pagingControl](https://github.com/Moulay92/com.developatic.pagingControl). I hope that will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS you can have a look at the property `clipViews`. For Android it is currently not possible without adjusting the SDK. Have a look at this ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25635. It is a feature request to have this kind of layout. Also it features some links that explain how to add it to the sdk.